# How can i show only the largest number from my output?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, integer

In this program I am trying to show the longest consecutive numbers.
(For example: input: `1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3`, output: `3 4 5`)

My question is how can I show only the largest number from my output. In this example `5`.

We are not allowed to use Arrays, is there any other way to solve this problem?

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
        
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    int zahl = 0;
    int anzahl = -1;
    String maxString = "";
        
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) { 
              
        int i = sc.nextInt();
 
        if (anzahl == i | anzahl == -1) {
            zahl++;
        } else if(anzahl != i) {
            maxString += zahl + "\n" ;
            zahl = 1;
        }
              
        anzahl = i;
    }
          
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(maxString + (zahl + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a variable to track the maximum number outside the loop, and change it when new subsequence is detected and after the loop to check the length of the last subsequence:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner("1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5");

int zahl = 0;
int anzahl = -1;
String maxString = "";
int maxFreq = 0; // maximal frequency of numbers

while (sc.hasNextInt()) { 
  
  int i = sc.nextInt();

  if(anzahl == i || anzahl == -1) {
      zahl++;
  } else {
      maxFreq = Math.max(maxFreq, zahl); // update maxFreq
      maxString += zahl + "\n" ;
      zahl = 1;
  }
  
  anzahl = i;
}
maxFreq = Math.max(maxFreq, zahl); // check the tail

sc.close();
//System.out.println(maxString + (zahl + 1) );
System.out.println("maxFreq=" + maxFreq);
```

prints `maxFreq=6` (the count of `4`s).

For this input `Scanner sc = new Scanner("1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2");` the code prints `maxFreq=7`

Answer (score 2):

(I don't have enough rep for a comment)

Additionally to what Alex wrote, you should also change the `else if(anzahl != i)` to just `else`.

Comment: It was a nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5");

    int letzter = 0;
    int anzahl = 0;
    String rekord = "";

    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int gegeben = sc.nextInt();


        if(letzter == -1 || letzter == gegeben) {
            anzahl++;
        } else {
            anzahl = 1;
        }

        if(rekord == ""){
            rekord = String.valueOf(gegeben);
        }else if(anzahl > rekord.length()) {
            rekord = String.format("%0" + anzahl + "d", 0).replace("0", String.valueOf(gegeben));
        }

        letzter = gegeben;
    }


    sc.close();
```

The String rekord really owns the current record and it can be overwrited.

(4ms running time)